Python + Polars: efficiently looking up a value in another DataFrame: replace or join?
Note to potential editors: please leave both "Python" and "Polars" in the question title, because:

there are many questions about looking up values in another dataframe in the pandas context;
not everyone (e.g. search engines, or beginners) knows how to use the [python-polars] tag to drill down to polars specific questions.


Python - Pandas x Polars - Values mapping (Lookup value) discusses a solution involving join or replace. What are the benefits of using replace over join, or vice versa?

map_dict was renamed to replace: https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.replace.html#polars.Expr.replace

@jqurious Oh that's so embarrassing. Whenever I was looking it up via Google, I was ending up on https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/version/0.18/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_dict.html
which is, now that I pay more careful attention, for version 0.18...thank you for the tip! Not sure if I should now delete this question.

Yeah, before 1.0 the method still existed but printed a DeprecationWarning. Perhaps editing the question to just show the before/after and removing mentions of map_dict is worthwhile. Internally, it performs a join: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/a5724d6e45039c04d52a3923c30eabb9c9738495/crates/polars-ops/src/series/ops/replace.rs#L158 so converting an existing DataFrame to a dict in order to use it is probably not the best for efficiency.

@jqurious I updated the question as you suggested. I think your comment could work well as an answer. It could also be an answer to the other question; it contradicts the accepted answer suggesting "there is not much of a difference" or some of the comments  suggesting that "replace is the preferred method". Ultimately, it seems to me that python-polars is missing something fundamental in its expressions, because there is no way to express that certain DataFrames live in the same "name-space" on the Rust-end, and therefore can be cheaply referred to.

The pragmatic solution I guess is to not use Python. Do it all in Rust?

No, when you call .replace() in Python - that Rust code is executed. It was just to demonstrate that .replace() is implemented using a .join internally. So you may as well use .join directly instead of turning a DataFrame into a dictionary.
